# Как сделать функцию доступной во всем приложении Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Как сделать набор функций который будет доступен во всех компонентах приложения Vue Js?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: [app.config.globalProperties](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties)

Comment: @Grundy большое спасибо! именно то что нужно

Comment: https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря @Grundy найдено решение:
использовано [app.config.globalProperties](https://vuejs.org/api/application.html#app-config-globalproperties)